# Formatting footnotes

Tags: support, markdown

Is there a way to format footnote references in questions or answers? I try `[1]` as I usually do in my plain-text e-mails, but this doesn't look good, [here is a live example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24078653/2932052).

Answer (score 74, accepted):

I typically use a horizontal rule in combination with `<sup>`. I don't use `<sub>` for the content as per Martijn's answer though<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup> Because it make the footnotes too small, IMO.

Comment: +1 good point, I used <sup>[1]</sup> now also under the <hr> different fonts make it easier to get. Ah, only now I see that this was your original suggestion.

Comment: Yeah, and when you have to use backticks in the footnote, the fixed-width font tends to get too large as well.

Comment: Hey; your footnote seems too large. `</tooObviousAndSmartAss>`

Comment: Any one know of a way to *anchor* the footnote and link to it?

Comment: @G.AllenMorrisIII, the anchor seems does not work for footnote. A least I can not make it work.

Comment: I think `<sub>` looks great for purely url footnote content (but agree, it's not useful for sentences).

Comment: *Suggested edits are not allowed on non-tag-wiki posts on meta sites.* - Too bad for me when I wanted to **see (not edit)** the markdown source code. In this case I figured it out anyway.

Comment: @Henke. ["There is a workaround for this"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/333836).

Comment: one problem with these tags is that it disables markdown after them. E.g. I'm yet to figure out how to format `some code` there

Answer (score 41):

I used to use some superscript / subscript formatting; `<sup>` tags for the reference, then combining that with `<sub>` in the footnote:

```
Markdown does not have explicit footnote support, so I use 
HTML<sup>*</sup> instead. Personally, I prefer using `*` or `†` for 
footnote markers, but you can use numbered<sup>[1]</sup> markers if 
you really want.

<sup>*<sub> This is the footnote text</sub></sup>  
<sup>[1]<sub> Number them any way you like</sub></sup>
```

which is rendered as

> Markdown does not have explicit footnote support, so I use
> HTML<sup>*</sup> instead. Personally, I prefer using `*` or `†` for
> footnote markers, but you can use  numbered<sup>[1]</sup> markers if
> you really want.
>
> <sup>* <sub>This is the footnote text</sub></sup>
> <sup>[1] <sub>Number them any way you like</sub></sup>

These days I do what Jon does (with a horizontal line before the footnotes), as I agree that adding `<sup>` makes the text too small.

Comment: Hey, that looks great (and solves my problem)

Comment: The dagger is definitely preferable when answering a question about a language that uses asterisks to mean something special (e.g. pointers).

Comment: @CodyGray sure, but subscript numbers are easier to write for programmers, provided there is always a <sup> in the clipboard ;)

Comment: It *looks* great, but the font *is* small indeed. My +1 is valid, but for pragmatic reasons, Jon's answer is the more acceptable for me. Thanks for your effort with including the source as well. BTW: the length of the first line causes a horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: @Wolf: sure, not a problem. Reflowed the formatted portion.

Comment: [The sub and sup elements](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_sup)

Comment: FYI, while editing a question (that included keyboard shortcuts using `<kbd>`), trying to add footnotes resulted in the dreaded "Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code" error. Presumably due to the density of HTML tags. I played around with it for a bit, ended up dropping the idea of using footnotes.

Answer (score 21):

Just a small modification of [Martijn Pieters' answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258598/2586922): if the footnote spans more than one line, his sub-within-sup approach gives too large line spacing compared with font size. Also, the text is perhaps too small. For example,

```
Example body text. Now, surprise, comes a footnote<sup>1</sup>.

<sup>1<sub> This is the footnote text, which spans several lines. Compare the
rendered text in the first and second approaches. I find the second one more
pleasing, and easier to read. What do you think? </sub></sup>
```

is rendered as

> Example body text. Now, surprise, comes a footnote<sup>1</sup>.
>
> <sup>1 <sub>This is the footnote text, which spans several lines.
>   Compare the rendered text in the first and second approaches. I find
>   the second one more pleasing, and easier to read. What do you think?</sub></sup>

I prefer the following approach, which gives **better-looking line spacing**. Also, **the text is slightly larger**, and thus easier to read.

```
Example body text. Now, surprise, comes a footnote<sup>1</sup>.

<sup><sup>1</sup> This is the footnote text, which spans several lines. Compare
the rendered text in the first and second approaches. I find the second one more
pleasing, and easier to read. What do you think? </sup>
```

is rendered as

> Example body text. Now, surprise, comes a footnote<sup>1</sup>.
>
> <sup><sup>1</sup> This is the footnote text, which spans several
>   lines. Compare the rendered text in the first and second approaches. I
>   find the second one more pleasing, and easier to read. What do you
>   think?</sup>

Comment: Nice, but, wouldn't a real list be better in this case?

Comment: @Wolf Sorry, what do you mean by "a real list"?

Comment: I thought of the ol HTML tag. I think the text should better not float around the number... but this is only a minor issue not worth the trouble.

Comment: @Wolf: If you use a real numbered list at the bottom, someone might confuse it for a continuation of the body. By using a tiny `1` in `<sup>` tags, the list is clearly a footnote section. To further help the cause, a horizontal line should be used too. See [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/378193/35690) for more info.

Comment: @Senseful Much better with the horizontal line!

Answer (score 12):

Apologies for a another response, but I've found the perfect combination to incorporate elements of all the recommendations above.

Namely:

1. Use `<sup>1</sup>` for the footnote references. Using numbers is a lot easier to remember than a [list of symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Note_(typography)#Numbering_and_symbols), and looks nicer, since their heights will always be equal (as opposed to `*` and `†`, for example).
2. Use a [horizontal line](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258599/35690) to separate the footnotes section, [making it clear](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258597/formatting-footnotes/378193#comment658274_267846) that it's not just a continuation of the body.
3. Use a `<sup>` tag to render the footnote definitions in small text, again making it clear that it's a footnote section. Don't use `<sub>` as it [won't wrap as nicely](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258598/35690).
4. Use a second `<sup>` tag for each number in the footnote section, again making it clear that it's a footnote definition and not part of the body.
5. Use [double spaces](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/267846/35690) to separate footnote lines, so that the definition numbers line up.

## Template

```
Example<sup>1</sup> text.<sup>2</sup>

---
<sup><sup>1</sup> Definition goes here.</sup>  
<sup><sup>2</sup> Definition goes here.</sup>
```

## Rendered Template

Example<sup>1</sup> text.<sup>2</sup>

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> Definition goes here.</sup>
<sup><sup>2</sup> Definition goes here.</sup>

Answer (score 3):

### Recipe:

```
Although the there is a relevant post elsewhere in the network with
`status-declined`<sup>1</sup>, the markdown help page here<sup>2</sup> can indeed... help.

<hr>

1. <sub><sup>[Markdown footnotes?][^1]</sup></sub>
2. <sub><sup>[Markdown help: Advanced Links][^2]</sup></sub>

  [^1]: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5017/markdown-footnotes "Meta Stack Exchange"
  [^2]: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#advanced-links "Stack Overflow"
```

## Results:

Although the there is a relevant post elsewhere in the network with 
`status-declined`<sup>1</sup>, the markdown help page here<sup>2</sup> can indeed... help.

---

1. <sub><sup>[Markdown footnotes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5017/markdown-footnotes)</sup></sub>
2. <sub><sup>[Markdown help: Advanced Links](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#advanced-links)</sup></sub>

Comment: The font for the footnote text is really very small. This approach is sadly also just a hack, at least in the present MD implementation. The footnotes are not classified as such, So you can not apply CSS on it to fix the the font sizes.