# Backticks in <sub> text reset font size

Tags: discussion, bug, design, code-formatting

I was just using some back-ticked text in a subscript-size note, in this question:

[How do I use cmake to ensure a C++14 compiler links with the experimental filesystem TS library?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50172835/1593077)

and noticed the text within them is rendered at the same size as non-<‎sub>ed backticked text:

`aaa` <sub>`aaa`</sub>

Comment: I cannot think of a valid situation where you'd have to use code blocks in a `<sub>`.

Comment: @the4kman: Have you actually followed the link?

Comment: I don't consider using subscripts for footnotes too lucky. They can just be formatted as normal body-sized text.

Comment: @the4kman: If you find no valid use case, it follows you can also think of no valid case in which someone will be inconvenienced by making backticked text in <sub>'s smaller. In that case, you should agree with my request for this style change by default. :-)

Comment: Subscript font is actually slightly *larger* than the inline-code code font, so you aren't really going to notice a problem unless you're going multiple layers deep. https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2bAg.png

Comment: @Draco18s: No, it isn't - see discussion under Cerbrus' answer.

Comment: Yes, I did. And I couldn't tell what the problem was until I clicked "edit" to look for the subscript sections. https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQF4S.png

Comment: This looks like the same issue as I reported here: [Code wrapped inside sub/superscripts is too big](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358590/code-wrapped-inside-sub-superscripts-is-too-big)

Comment: Using superscript or subscript for footnotes is semantically wrong (according to the HTML5 specs). Hence there is no reason to expect it to render well.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand: Interesting. And can you remind us please what the syntax is for writing a footnote using Stackoverflow Markdown without the performing the grave mistake of using <sub>?

Answer (score 4):

That's because the font-size for back-ticked code blocks is defined by this css rule:

```
.post-text code, 
.wmd-preview code {
  font-size: 13px;
}
```

While sup/sup text is sized with this rule:

```
sup, 
sub {
  font-size: 80%;
}
```

The code's `font-size` overrides the parent sub/sup's `font-size`.

---

I'd argue that for simplicity's sake, it's better to keep it this way. Code blocks in super / subscript doesn't seem that common.

Comment: 1. How is it more simple this way? 2. Their not being common only reduces the impact of a change, it doesn't make an inappropriate change better nor an appropriate change worse...

Comment: 1: separation of style per element. ("Code looks like X, pre looks like Y"). 2: it _does_ affect the significance and importance of the change.  In the end, it's a difference between `font-size: 12px;` and `font-size: 13px;`. You need a good set of eyes to even notice it.

Comment: 1. By saying "80%  size" you're already committing to non-separation. You're just making it inconsistent IMO 2. 80% of 13 is 10.4, which with rounding is 10.5. If you follow my link you'll see it's quite an eyesore.

Comment: @einpoklum: the calculated size of the sub / sup elements is 12px. At least, that’s what Chrome tells me.

Comment: Ah, yes, I see. With chromium, I get a font size of 15px for normal text, and then there's 13px for the backticked code and 12px for the subscript. So it is a ration of 80%, and we should get backticked text at 10.4px (or 10, or 11) when subscripted.