# Could we have proper footnote elements?

Tags: feature-request, markdown, formatting

### Problem

We currently don't have a dedicated way to create footnotes (although there are [some workarounds here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258597)). The most commonly used approach is to use `<sub>` or `<sup>` tags. However, these have several issues:

1. The font size is too small.
2. The line height is too big. This is visible in multiple lines on top of each other.
3. Vertically poorly aligned when next to normal rows. (Too near or far.)
4. Tags don't have semantic meaning. (Compared to blockquote, for example)

### Proposed solution

Introduce a new block style element type for footnotes. It would have a slightly smaller font-size and line height, but otherwise similar to a normal text paragraph.

The syntax wouldn't need to be super concise. If there isn't any easy way to have a Markdown tag, a simple inline HTML element could do, for example `<footnote>This is my footnote.</footnote>`.

### Use cases

1. Adding information that is helpful, but not necessarily to the core of the answer. This happens with longer answers of more complex topics, where we don't want to use comments.
2. Using with blockquotes for styling purposes, when quoting parts from documents that use them (for example, the [C standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_C))

---

Comment: You should listen to Jill https://i.stack.imgur.com/tI7It.png

Comment: Can you give some examples where footnotes would be necessary?

Comment: I never had any problem using sup and sub tags for this. Foot notes are per definition not very important stuff, so who cares about how they appear visually.

Comment: @user438383 Like when stating sources and formal references in an answer, but the exact reference isn't as important as the fact that you aren't just making things up yourself.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I am not sure how opinion is good argument against using them.

Comment: @Lundin Perhaps visual preference is subjective. But I do care.

Comment: *If* footnotes are added, I'd love for the syntax to follow [pandoc Markdown](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-footnotes), or [GitHub-flavoured Markdown](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/writing-on-github/getting-started-with-writing-and-formatting-on-github/basic-writing-and-formatting-syntax#footnotes) instead of inventing new syntax: `Text[^1]` and then `[^1]: Footnote`. Pandoc also supports inline footnotes: `Text.[^This is a footnote.]`

Comment: @BenjaminW. That would be even better. I didn't know such syntax existed already.

Comment: Ideally, such footnotes would be clickable to jump to the footnote, with a "return" link to jump back up to where the footnote is referenced in the post.

Comment: Related (using the same proxy for footnotes): *[Editing old questions to add links to similar ones](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419863/editing-old-questions-to-add-links-to-similar-ones/419864#419864)*. Wasn't there a follow-up to that regarding footnotes? Perhaps on [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tour)?

Comment: There is no `<footnote>` element in HTML...

Comment: @HereticMonkey nor runnable code snippets.

Comment: I'm more of a practicalist than a theorist on this.  I've used the `<sub>` tags in the past and they've been just fine for me, IMO.  Maybe to get more context into this, what specific examples can you point to that would benefit from the use of better footnotes?

Comment: For citing sources, I'd think in most cases it can be done the way most folks have done it in the comments here. So while I'm not against this, I agree with Makoto that it'd be useful to see example posts.

Comment: @Lundin sub/sup are clumsy to use, and *semantically* wrong, which means they can e.g. confuse screen readers.